# How do I set buffer for MP4 in FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, buffer, mp4

I convert videos to MP4 for my web player. My problem is: My videos don't buffer. I have to wait until the whole video is downloaded, and after that, I can play the video.

This is my `exec()` command:

```
ffmpeg -i uploaded_files/'.$le["file"].' -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p flash/'.$le["file"].'.mp4
```

Are there any options for buffering? My MP4 size and quality is good. But without buffering, it's bad.

Is this the fault of the `exec()` command I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My videos don't buffer. I have to wait until the whole video is downloaded, and after that, I can play the video.

Use the `-movflags faststart` option while encoding, e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 […] -movflags faststart output.mp4
```

Or, alternatively, run [`qt-faststart`](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/qtfaststart) on the file.

The reason the files don't stream immediately is that their [MOOV atom](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/video/articles/mp4_movie_atom.html) is at the end of the file, and in order to play it, the client needs  to parse this info. `qt-faststart` will just move that atom and your files will start playing right away.

Comment: I tried thos: `$cmd = 'ffmpeg -i uploaded_files/160971517551170c3698a5f-Kukori_es_Kotkoda_1.evad_08.resz_-_Kakasviadal.avi -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset medium -movflags faststart test/'.date("H-i-s").'.mp4';` but it writes: nable to parse option value "faststart"
Invalid value 'movflags' for option 'faststart' 
Do you know what is wrong? (Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'faststart')

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is because your FFmpeg version is too old. You're using the deprecated and ambiguous `-preset` as well. Consider downloading [a static build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) from their homepage or [compiling a newer version](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/CompilationGuide) yourself if you can (and have admin rights on the machine).

Comment: Note that using `qt-faststart` is independent from whatever FFmpeg version you're using. That being said, it's never a bad idea to update FFmpeg as it's constantly developed—hundreds of bugs are fixed within a few months time. And you'd miss out on new features.

Comment: ffmpeg version 0.7.13, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun 13 2012 14:14:09... Now I try update, but I'm bad linux user.. :-)

Comment: You can just try a static build, it'll work without installation.

Comment: Can't I use faststart with this version of ffmpeg? Or any other solution for this .mp4 thing?

Comment: As I said, you can use `qt-faststart` even with your old FFmpeg version. But I don't see a convincing reason to stay with the old release.